# верификация email

Tags: javascript, firebase

В firebase выставил аутентификацию с помощью email. Но не могу найти, как верифицировать email.

Может есть какая-та настройка в firebase, что бы при регистрации сразу отправлялось письмо с подтверждением? (Делаю тестовый проект на react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [документации](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users), письмо с верификацией отправляется методом `.sendEmailVerification()`.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
  // Email sent.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Шаблон письма тоже можно настраивать.